# Karate tests - Key inputs not working when running in Docker

Tags: docker, automated-tests, karate

Using karate I have some issue when the maven project is run in docker - Ubuntu, Firefox and Geckodriver. There are is no real effect when keys are pressed (Key inputs). The steps are performed (in test report are run successfully), but there is no key press in browser. I have also tries it with alpine linux the problem is still the same. It seems, that Key commands not working (e.g.: * input('body', Key.TAB) or * input('body', Key.TAB ) etc...). When I run it locally without Docker, it works fine, key strokes are done.

part of the code:

```
* input('body', Key.TAB)
* input('body', Key.DOWN)
* input('body', Key.DOWN)
* input('body', Key.DOWN)
* input('body', Key.DOWN)
* input('body', Key.DELETE)
```

Do you have some idea what is the problem?
Is there anybody who also encounter this issue?

Comment: nope, no idea. we mainly focus on the chrome docker. this also depends on third-party webdriver pieces. I strongly suggest you contribute research or influence others to do so. and this is the first time I am hearing of this problem